# how to use python asyncio_redis correctly?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, async-await, redis

I've used `asyncio_redis` in my `fastapi`,

however, when I deploy this api in `docker container`, it cannot work successfully.

I use `client.py` to request, and get the `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()`

#### API

```py
import asyncio
import asyncio_redis
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
REDIS_PORT = 6379

async def write_to_redis():
    print("test1")

    redis_client = await asyncio_redis.Pool.create(
            host=HOST,
            port=REDIS_PORT,
            poolsize=6
    )

    print("test2")

    try:
        
        await redis_client.set('e12345', 'hi')
        print("test3")

    finally:
        redis_client.close()
        await redis_client.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(write_to_redis())

"""
@app...

@app...

"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app="io_redis:app", host=HOST, port=8000, reload=True)
```

#### Client.py

```py
import requests

host = "http://localhost:8000/"
url = f"{host}"

res = requests.get(url)

if res.status_code == 200:
    print(res.json())
else:
    print("Error: ", res.text)
```

#### Result from Client.py

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Then, I tried to checkout problem in api via `docker exec -it <containerID> sh`,

I find this api execute successfully until `await asyncio_redis.Pool.create()`. (cannot print test2)

Note: The redis connection is work which can return `PONG` when I send `ping` in redis server.